# SQL Get the sum of a column based on last record for the selected date per year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables that look like this

**AccountBalance**

| AccountID | Balance | BeginDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 100 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-04-15 |
| 5678 | 50 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-07-10 |
| 1234 | 30 | 2023-04-16 | 2023-07-10 |

BeginDate to EndDate is the period of time in which the balance is true for the specific account.

**Account**

| AccountID | AccountNumber | Location | SubLocation | Responsible |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | Spain | Madrid | Evan |
| 5678 | 2 | Germany | Frankfurt | Esther |

How can I get a result table like this??

| Location | SubLocation | Responsible | Year | Month | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | Madrid | Evan | 2023 | 1 | 100 |
| Spain | Madrid | Evan | 2023 | 2 | 100 |
| Spain | Madrid | Evan | 2023 | 3 | 100 |
| Spain | Madrid | Evan | 2023 | 4 | 30 |
| Spain | Madrid | Evan | 2023 | 5 | 30 |
| Spain | Madrid | Evan | 2023 | 6 | 30 |
| Spain | Madrid | Evan | 2023 | 7 | 30 |
| Germany | Frankfurt | Esther | 2023 | 1 | 50 |
| Germany | Frankfurt | Esther | 2023 | 2 | 50 |
| Germany | Frankfurt | Esther | 2023 | 3 | 50 |
| Germany | Frankfurt | Esther | 2023 | 4 | 50 |
| Germany | Frankfurt | Esther | 2023 | 5 | 50 |
| Germany | Frankfurt | Esther | 2023 | 6 | 50 |
| Germany | Frankfurt | Esther | 2023 | 7 | 50 |

1. There could be multiple responsible per location/Sublocation
2. There could be multiple SubLocations per Location
3. The Balance on month 4 for Spain is 30 due to we are looking at the end of the month.

The resultset is a summary per month of the balance per location, sublocation, responsible, year and month.

I have attempted

```
WITH BalanceSummary
        AS(
            SELECT 
                a.Location as Location
                ,a.SubLocation as subLocation
                ,a.Responsible as Responsible
                ,a.AccountNumber
                ,ab.BeginDate as BeginDate
                ,ab.EndDate as EndDate
                ,ab.Balance as Balance
    
              FROM [AccountBalance] ab
              JOIN [Account] a
              ON ab.AccountID = a.AccountID
              WHERE
              a.ApplicationCode <> 'lna'
              )
    
    SELECT  bs.AccountNumber
            ,bs.Location
            ,bs.SubLocation
            ,bs.Responsible
        --  ,MAX(bs.BeginDate) as BeginDate
            ,(SELECT TOP 1 b2.Balance FROM BalanceSummary b2 WHERE b2.AccountNumber = bs.AccountNumber order by b2.BeginDate DESC) as BalanceYesterday
    FROM BalanceSummary bs
    Group by bs.AccountNumber, bs.Location, bs.SubLocation, bs.Responsible
```

This is as far as I gotten, but this only brings me the latest snapshot, not the "snapshot per month". And even though it brings the latest snapshot, it is not efficiente as it takes almost 5 mins.

Comment: There are no question marks in your text, and stackoverflow is not a free code service. If you have some specific coding issues, you might wanna re-phrase this before it closes

Comment: you appear to have omitted to include your current attempt and explained the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have edited, I don't know if I can be more focused, I have spent more than a day trying to resolve this, but I have not gotten really close to the answer. As I stated, I'm level beginner in SQL commands.

Comment: you can do something like this perhaps: https://dbfiddle.uk/ihg_eKCx it creates year + month data and then try to find the last balance per that date

Comment: Yes and No, this takes me real close to the solution, but as you can see in the result set, Im not giving detail of the account, but an aggregation of location, sublocation .. and I wish to sum the balance ... Im still running the code to see what it shows ...

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "sum the balance". The sum of the balances for the Madrid account is 100+100+...30 = 420. The sum of the balances for the Frankfurt account is 7 * 50 = 350. Both values are dimensionally meaningless. Siggemannen's answer (fiddle link) is correct for the problem as described at this point. My only suggestion is that you might need to generalize with a calendar table to handle the year/month range. If you need something different, you need to expand on your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution with a calendar as it was suggested in the comments because the year can be different. Maybe it will give an idea how to improve your code in case of "sum the balance".

```sql
create table AccountBalance(AccountID int, Balance int, BeginDate date, EndDate date)

insert into AccountBalance
values
(1234, 100, '2023-01-01', '2023-04-15'),
(5678, 50, '2023-01-01', '2023-07-10'),
(1234, 30, '2023-04-16', '2023-07-10')

create table Account(AccountID int, AccountNumber int, Location varchar(255), SubLocation varchar(255), Responsible varchar(255))

insert into Account
values
(1234, 1, 'Spain', 'Madrid', 'Evan'),
(5678, 2, 'Germany', 'Frankfurt', 'Esther')

create table #dates(dates date)

declare @min_date date
       ,@max_date date; 

select @min_date = min(BeginDate), @max_date = max(EndDate) from AccountBalance;

--calendar table with all existed dates from min to max
while @min_date <= @max_date
  begin
    insert into #dates
    values (@min_date)
    set @min_date  = dateadd(day, 1, @min_date)
  end;

--apply balance for each calculated date and then take only the latest one within Location, SubLocation, Responsible
with cte as(
select row_number()over(partition by a.Location, a.SubLocation, a.Responsible, year(dates), month(dates) order by dates DESC) rn, a.Location as Location
      ,a.SubLocation as subLocation
      ,a.Responsible as Responsible
      ,year(dates) as [Year]
      , month(dates) as [Month]
      ,ab.Balance 
from AccountBalance ab
inner join #dates on dates >= ab.BeginDate and dates <= ab.EndDate
inner join Account a on a.AccountID = ab.AccountID
)
select Location, subLocation, Responsible, [Year], [Month], Balance from cte where rn = 1
```

[image]